# macOS Sierra not support Xcode6.4?

Tags: macos, xcode6, macos-sierra

After upgrading **macOS Sierra**, open the xcode6 will flash back.

In the apple forum, it seems that some people have encountered the same problem, but [no one answered](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50330) yet!
Crash log in this problem description.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to [this problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6050819?tstart=0), as the call stacks look similar

Comment: Facing same issue. Any Solution??

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want to use an ancient version of Xcode on the latest version of the OS? I, personally, wouldn't expect it to work at all.